# Calculating the probability to win a given tournement

Tags: probability

I'm trying to set up a win prediction tool for a small game I'm currently working on.
Players compete against each other in a tournament, where each player plays against everyone. The player with the most wins at the end takes all.
I already figured out, how to calculate the probability in which a player wins a certain 1v1 match. So let's say `GetP(player1, player2)` equals the chance of player1 winning against player2 in a 1v1.
What I can't figure out tho is how to use this information to get the tournament winning percentage of a specific player, because it's not fixed how often he has to win, it depends on how everyone else plays as well.

Do you have some ideas on how to solve that?
Thank's in advance.

Comment: The average of all the probabilities of wining against other players should be a representative of player1’s winning percentage.

Comment: @VishaalSudarsan I know that there are ways of getting a value which is somewhat like the exact, but I'm aiming for the most exact as it can get...

Comment: Since the probability of $P_i$ winning against $P_j$ is different for each i and j, a closed form solution would be very ugly. If you're ready to assume that all players have 50% chances of winning against each other, probably there is a way out.

Comment: Unfortunately, each player has a unique winning rate.